# Zend Error controller stopped working for 500

Tags: zend-framework, error-handling

My Zend application was running fine until today, when I changed something which caused the error controller to stop working.
I have debugged every part of the code but I can not find any traces as to why is it happening

If I produce a 404 error, the error controller runs perfectly. But in case of 500, the control does not go to error controller.

I have tried many things but am still unable to find out what's wrong. I have searched the internet but people who encountered this problem, seemed to get no answer :(

Any help would be much appreciable

I have debugged the application step by step and found out that in case of 500, the execution stops instantly when it encounters a fatal error or exception

(UPDATE)
If I do something like...

```
$blabla->getInfo();
```

where $blabla is not defined, I don't get redirected to error controller.
But if I do something like...

```
Zend_Registry::get('blabla');
```

where no key is set for 'blabla' in Zend_Registry, then I get redirected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

500 is a general server error, so no wonder the control does not go to your controller.

You will need to check your server logs to find out what is causing the error.

Also, try to recall whether you have altered your `.htaccess` file(s) recently and/or created an infinite redirect loop by accident.

Comment: Thanks for the response :)
I haven't changed .htaccess ever, and there's no infinite loop because I can see the error if I set error reporting to true.

Another thing to share, if the fatal error is due to Zend_Exception, then the error controller runs but if it's just a fatal error, then it doesn't :(

Comment: As far as I remember, the error controller used to run for every kind of error/exception. I remember getting emails from my error controller logic about the same scenario I have created.