# New Zend added controllers stopped working showing error 500 for New Controllers, Previous Controllers Working fine

Tags: php, zend-framework

My Zend application was running fine until today, when I changed something( i mean literally nothing) which caused new controllers to stop working. I have debugged every part of the code but I can not find any traces as to why is it happening!

**My Previous added controls are working**, and new actions added to those also,
but new added controls dont work.

Error is this:
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

same situation like this question:

[Zend Error controller stopped working for 500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208783/zend-error-controller-stopped-working-for-500)

Any body having a solution! Please Reply, 
I replaced every bit , of apache ,zend ,php library sources with new one, but with no success.

Comment: Could you give some explanation what you changed?  If it's stating an "Internal Server Error" What do your Apache error logs show? That might help us troubleshoot a solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Whenever I get a 500 error in a zend app, it's usually because of something in public/index.php.  Might help to look there.

Comment: thanks  jmbertucci & liz for taking time to reply,
I literally changed nothing but now can't detect what is happening,

All other sites are working fine, but with this one app, i can't run a new added controller!

Comment: Below are laste entries of error log in apache:

[Wed Aug 08 18:47:22 2012] [notice] Child 5816: Child process is exiting
[Wed Aug 08 18:47:23 2012] [notice] Parent: Child process exited successfully.
[Wed Aug 08 18:47:39 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Aug 08 18:47:39 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Aug 08 18:47:41 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e PHP/5.3.8 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations

Comment: [Wed Aug 08 18:47:41 2012] [notice] Server built: Sep 10 2011 11:34:11
[Wed Aug 08 18:47:41 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 712
Apache server shutdown initiated...
[Wed Aug 08 18:47:42 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Aug 08 18:47:42 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Aug 08 18:47:44 2012] [notice] Child 712: Child process is running

Comment: [Wed Aug 08 18:47:44 2012] [notice] Child 712: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
[Wed Aug 08 18:47:44 2012] [error] (OS 10038)An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.  : winnt_accept: getsockname error on listening socket, is IPv6 available?
[Wed Aug 08 18:47:44 2012] [error] (OS 10038)An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.  : winnt_accept: getsockname error on listening socket, is IPv6 available?
[Wed Aug 08 18:47:45 2012] [notice] Child 712: Released the start mutex

Comment: Now point is i replaced fresh php.ini httpd configuration files, but with no success......

Comment: SO ANYONE HAVING ANY SOLUTION, I HAVE STUCK IN MY PROJECT AND THAT TOO IN ACADEMIC ONE.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have enough logging going on to troubleshoot this. Do you have a fatal error handler? Here is one that should help you see what's going on (Add to Boostrap class). Basically, it logs fatal errors to a log file and displays a static html page to the user.

```
/**
 * Fatal Error Catcher which runs as a registered shutdown function
 */
public static function fatalErrorCatcher() {
    $error = error_get_last();
    if ($error && (
            $error['type'] === E_ERROR ||
            $error['type'] === E_COMPILE_ERROR ||
            $error['type'] === E_CORE_ERROR ||
            $error['type'] === E_PARSE
    )) {
        // kill the buffer content, it's broken anyway
        while (ob_get_level()) {
            ob_end_clean();
        }
        // make a summary of the error
        $errorSummary = date('m/d/Y G:i:s') . ' '
            . $error['message'] . ' on file ' . $error['file'] . ':' . $error['line'] . ' URL:'
            . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]
            . ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80" ? ":" . $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] : "")
            . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] . "\n";
        // log the error to file
        file_put_contents('/var/log/fata-errors.log', $errorSummary, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        // tell the user we're sorry
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
        echo file_get_contents('/var/www/html/fail-whale.html');
    }
}
```

AND You register it in bootstrap as early in the init as possible:

```
register_shutdown_function(array('Bootstrap', 'fatalErrorCatcher'));
```